# How to change external function variable from internal jquery event function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can change external function variable from internal function?

Example:

```
function ExternalFunction() {
    var $element = $('#my-element'); // Some jquery object
    var my_variable = 'value';

    $element.click(function() {
        // Here I want to change "my_variable" value.
        // But I can't change it with "my_variable = 'new value';".
    })
}
```

How I can change my_variable in internal function?

**Update1:**

I haven't error, but I can't change variable from internal function. See example please:

http://jsfiddle.net/ye0qhu0v/4/

Comment: You should be able to, there must be a different error.

Comment: This is perfectly possible. Please show us the error you get in console.

Comment: This is not possible as you are doing because at a time one event can be fire.. You will call your function on other event and the click event will not fire at that time.

Comment: What error you getting ??

Comment: You can change it, and the code in the question that you've commented out *will* change it. You have different code in the JS Fiddle which fails for a completely different reason, but it should be part of your question if you want an answer about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use **ExternalFunction**() inside DOM ready,Declare the function outside DOM ready

**Works perfectly,**

```
function ExternalFunction() {
    var $element = $('#my-element'); // Some jquery object
    var my_variable = 'value';

        $('#my-element').on('click', function() {
            // Here I want to change "my_variable" value.
            // But I can't change it with "my_variable = 'new value';".
             my_variable = 'new value';//here we are assigning new value to the variable
            console.log(my_variable);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, may be I have problem because I use .click() ? Please see Update1 in Question description.

Comment: @user3775292 you cant use ExternalFunction() iside DOM ready, here is my modified code http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/ye0qhu0v/5/

Comment: Please, Ask the following questions:

Comment: 2) How I can toggle the toggle value (true/false)?

Comment: I found the answer for second question, my mistake, what about 1) ?

Comment: Why you need to call the ExternalFunction() inside DOM ready, pointless isn't it ?

Comment: Please don't ask me why. I want to understand why It isn't possible.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you using `ExternalFunction` inside DOM Ready (and no reason to make it a global function).

Comment: Ok, Quentin. CodingAnt, Thanks for help!

Comment: Moving `ExternalFunction` won't solve the problem (and is bad practise). Adding the uncommented line `my_variable = 'new value';//here we are assigning new value to the variable` solves the problem.